# Are string functions ASCII-safe in PHP?

Tags: php, string, internationalization, ascii, locale

Some PHP [string functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.strings.php) (like strtoupper, etc) are locale dependent. But it is still not clear whether locale is important when I do really know that particular string is made of ASCII (0-127) characters only. Can I be guaranteed that `strtoupper('abc..xyz')` will always return `ABC..XYZ` independently of locale. Do PHP [string functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.strings.php) work the same in ASCII range independently of locale?

While the answer about `strtoupper` is important to me, the question is more general about all string functions library.

I want to be sure that user selected locale (on a multi-language site) will not break my core functionality which has nothing to do with internationalization.

Comment: Do you mean if the `mod_php` or `FastCGI` engine is run with e.g. `LANG=de_DE` or `LANG=ru_RU.koi8`? Or do you mean something else..?

Comment: I don't know, maybe it has much in common when speaking about default locale, so it can be the same thing. But I mean locale which is set using setlocale().

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Do PHP string functions work the same in ASCII range independent from locale?

No, I'm afraid not. The primary counterexample is the dreaded Turkish [dotted-I](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I#In_computing):

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "tr_TR");
echo strtoupper('hi!');

-> 'H\xDD!' ('Hİ!' in ISO-8859-9)
```

In the worst case you may have to provide your own locale-independent string handling. Calling `setlocale` to revert to `C` or some other locale is kind-of a fix, but the POSIX process-level locale model is a really bad fit for modern client/server apps.

Comment: (I'm just hiding from my horror of a job... don't tell anyone you saw me!)

Comment: dude with that rep and the answers I've seen you should be able to get any job you want.

Comment: Clear. Thanks for the answer! So, it seems that it's better avoid to use the main PHP strings library for anything at all. The bad thing is that other libraries are not so comprehensive.

Answer (score 4):

PHP string functions treat one byte as one character. In the ASCII range `0-127` that is fine.

To safely handle multiple languages using UTF-8, use `mb_*()` functions, a UTF-8 library or wait til 2030 when PHP6 is released.

Comment: ___This___. Nothing to add. Yeah 2030, _if all goes well_.

Comment: I understand that PHP functions treats one byte as one character. But despite of this some PHP functions behave differently depending on locale if character range is 128-255. So, can I be sure that there is no such locale which instructs PHP functions to behave different in the range 0-127 too? Does this mean that all PHP supported locales have charsets which are only extended versions of ASCII (without modification in range 0-127)?

Comment: @Karolis I'm not sure if I understand that enough to answer. I'm sure someone else will come by with the right answer :)